# Функция ВПР неправильно работает, в чем проблема?

Tags: excel, office

Пытаюсь выбрать данные из таблицы с помощью функции `ВПР`.

Какую бы ячейку не брал в искомое значение, всегда выбирает именно одну запись
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы привели пример таблицы, и Интервальный просмотр ставите 0 (это точное совпадение, пусто или 1 - это приближенное значение)?

Comment: при интервальном ошибка

Comment: 07.11.2018| 204 |0491279A664F80 - таблица

Comment: Таблица из 1 строки все правильно?

Comment: там 1 значение беру, которое искомое, что не правильного

Comment: вы не искомое берете, вы сравниваете "0449189A664F80" с "07.11.2018" т.к. ВПР ищет искомое значение в крайнем левом столбце, если интервальный просмотр ставите 0 - ошибка, т.к. нет точного совпадения, если ставите пусто то возвращает значение в 3 столбце последней строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВПР работает правильно, если правильно ее применять. Справку внимательно читать нужно. Даже в подсказке на картинке из заглавного сообщения написано: "Ищет значение **в крайнем левом столбце** таблицы".

Без перестановки столбцов поможет *ИНДЕКС+ПОИСКПОЗ*:

```
=ИНДЕКС($A$2:$A$10;ПОИСКПОЗ(F2;$C$2:$C$10;))
```

Еще вариант:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/($C$2:$C$10=F2);$A$2:$A$10)
```

Можно и с *ВПР* извернуться - сформировать для нее диапазон внутри функции, переставив столбцы:

```
=ВПР(F2;ЕСЛИ({1;0};$C$2:$C$10;$A$2:$A$10);2;)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена заменой столбцов. Поставив его в начале, всё заработало